# Determine which trigger was triggered with task execution in Windows 10 Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I wonder if its possible to figure out which trigger was triggered when my own task was scheduled in the Windows 10 task scheduler?

I would like to debug the behaviour of the task scheduling in my case with multiple trigger set up for a task.

I enabled task logging in the Task Scheduler but I dont seem to find this information in the logs.

I also inspected the Get-ScheduledTask and .Triggers object in PowerShell but there was no such method or info by a quick glance at least.